# How to add element in UWP pivot from other XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have this XAML code with one Pivot element. I want to add the elements instead of the `TextBlock` from other XAML. Here's my code:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid RequestedTheme="Default">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="978*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Pivot Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <PivotItem Header="All">
                <TextBlock Text="All works here" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Important">
                <TextBlock Text="Important works goes here" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Pending">
                <TextBlock Text="Pending works goes here" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Done">
                <TextBlock Text="Done works goes here" />
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Can somebody please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by _add the elements instead of the TextBlock from other XAML_? Do you want to add other controls not only TextBlock in the PivotItem?

Comment: By element, I mean any other UWP component

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Or If I understand right, you want to add custom control into the PivotItem?

Comment: Yes I want custom control to Pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to add a custom control into the PivotItem. I don't know what does your custom control looks like so I made a custom control myself to show you how it should work. You could just replace it with your own custom control.

MainPage code:

```
 <Grid RequestedTheme="Default">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="978*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Pivot Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <PivotItem Header="All">
                <TextBlock Text="All works here" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Important">
                <!--this is the custom control I made-->
                <local:CustomTextBox x:Name="MycustomControl"/>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Pending">
                <TextBlock Text="Pending works goes here" />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Done">
                <TextBlock Text="Done works goes here" />
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

Custom control's code:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="InputBox" Width="600"/>
    <Button x:Name="ClickButton" Content="Please Click" Click="ClickButton_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayTextBlock" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

It's a simple custom control that combines a TextBox, a button, and a TextBlock.

And the result looks like this:
[image]

If you still have questions, please let me know